# Access to variables in root gradle build.gradle from subproject build.gradle?

Tags: groovy, gradle

I have a root build.gradle that contains some variables I want to have as global variables for some subprojects but not all sub projects

I created a list:

```
List spring_dependencies = [
    "org.springframework:spring-beans:$springVersion",
    "org.springframework:spring-core:$springVersion",
    "org.springframework:spring-web:$springVersion",
]
```

I have some suprojects that do NOT use this for compilation, so I want to only add:

```
compile spring_dependencies
```

to the projects that actually need spring.

How can I accomplish this global variable sharing in gradle?

Comment: Does `compile gradle.parent.spring_dependencies` work?  (not sure)

Comment: No, I get this error: > Cannot get property 'spring_dependencies' on null object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method I have just tried (and it seems to work) is to declare another sub-project (I called it 'spring'), which has the following `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile "org.springframework:spring-beans:$springVersion"
  compile "org.springframework:spring-core:$springVersion"
  compile "org.springframework:spring-web:$springVersion"
}
```

Add this project in to the `settings.gradle` list of sub-projects, then in the `build.gradle` that requires the spring libraries, you can do:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile project(':spring')
}
```

To extract the dependencies from your `spring` sub-project.

There might be a better way to achieve the same result... :-/